# Why does the C++ Standard define a partial ordering for cv qualifiers?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, volatile

The C++20 standard (checked on N4892) states:

> There is a partial ordering on cv-qualifiers, so that a type can be said to be more cv-qualified than another.
> Table 13 shows the relations that constitute this ordering.

6.8.4.5.

With table 13:

```
no cv-qualifier < const
no cv-qualifier < volatile
no cv-qualifier < const volatile
const           < const volatile
volatile        < const volatile
```

Although the definition is pretty clear and easy to understand, I wonder why it exists. I could not find another passage in the standard that makes use of this ordering (I might have missed something!). [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) has the same table, but also does not explain its use.

Why does this partial ordering exist?

Comment: Did you take a look at overload-resolution and pointer-/reference-assignment/compatibility?

Comment: For the sake of type conversions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just search for "more cv-qualified" in the standard document. There will be a lot of matches. Maybe the most obvious example:

```
char* pointer1;
...
const char* pointer2 = pointer1; // OK because it's more cv-qualified
```

In my opinion, if you are looking for common sense, just think about "const" instead of "cv".

Comment: You are right! I was looking for a reference to the number (6.8.4) but could not find any use that way. The fact that "more cv-qualified" is printed cursive in the standard probably would have been a good hint if I had noticed it.